# need to add more menu in geonetwork 3.10.2.0 home page I have now only Seach , map and sign in options

Tags: geonetwork

I need to add more menu in geonetwork 3.10.2.0 home page I have now only Seach , map and sign in options 
how can customize home page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom view. See docs about how to do it in [GeoNetwork website](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/customizing-application/search-ui/customview.html). You can find an example of custom view in [Dutch skin project](https://github.com/osgeonl/geonetwork-dutch-skin).